# Formula/algorithm to merge and sort arrays into one

Tags: mysql, php, arrays

I have four arrays that I need to merge/sort pragmatically.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e041YuQCUVu4_hgu1uCGaKILrL5a3WqReEeKtCeGLOs/edit?usp=sharing

The link above shows the contents of the arrays.

The left-most array is the desired array. The four other arrays are the data that I have to merge/sort in order to arrive at the desired array on the left.

I am very much capable of writing the code in PHP (the language I need to do this in), but I can't come up with the theory as to how to go about dealing with the data to arrive at the desired array.

Can anyone help me come up with a solution? This is a specific example but this same comparison will happen on around 400,000 other arrays like this. I just need the theory to get from the 4 arrays to 1 array.

Comment: How is the final order of the items decided? Is there some extra information that you have that would help us to determine that. What is the information about? Would that help us? It looks like 'public transport routes'. My first thoughts would be to add all the 'common items' to the output. Then add the 'remaining' ones. But I need to know the rules for where to insert them in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not about mysql, please remove the tag.  Otherwise, here is a solution of how to create a table from 4 other tables:

```
( SELECT x FROM array1 )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT x FROM array2 )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT x FROM array3 )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT x FROM array4 )
```

400K tables?  I hope not.